# SOAP guidance with IOS 5

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios5, soap

I'm a starter in Objective-C and IOS programming, and I'd like to have some recent guidance on how to use SOAP with IOS 5. I saw some tutorials online, but they are quite old (over a year old), and I don't really know if there are some more recent ways to deal with the SOAP webservices.

If anyone could give me some guidance / links about that, I'd be very pleased :)

Thanks !

Comment: Just ask for rest services on server side.

Comment: If you have control over what service the backend of your app uses, I'd highly recommend using a RESTful interface instead. Theres a reason why you don't see any `recent` articles on using iOS w/ a SOAP interface, little to no people use or prefer it.

Comment: I recommend reading this article http://geeknizer.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol/

Comment: @AlexTerente I agree 100% with you, but what happens if a company already has a soap webserice from a long time, and wants to integrate a new channel of communication like mobile. Must rewrite the webservice in Rest just for the mobile?

Comment: Thanks @AlexTerente, I'll think about using REST services :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really need** to use SOAP I suggest you to try [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/), you've to pass the `wsdl` to the service and this returns you a folder that contains the sample demo project with all the methods to call the webservice. In the folder you'll find also the documentation of your poject in html. You can also see the implementation file,  so you could adapt some functionality based on your requirements. For me this service was very helpful.

There are also other projects similar to SudzC, like [wdsl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/), but i didn't use this yet.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I'll make some tries with these two.